# What's the difference between using screen.getBy* vs just getBy* for react-testing-library?

Tags: react-testing-library

Is there any difference between using the global screen.getBy* vs the getBy destructured from a render?

e.g. screen

```
import {screen} from '@testing-library/react'

screen.getByText('hello');
```

vs.

```
import {render} from '@testing-library/react'

{getByText} from render(<div>hello</div>);
```

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of using `screen` is you no longer need to keep the render call destructure up-to-date as you add/remove the queries you need. You only need to type `screen` and let your editor's magic autocomplete take care of the rest.